# Hardcoding Maven debug flag in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I am running a build on gitlab, the pipeline currently inherits "mvn clean install" and the build is failing without any helpful logs (I also cannot run this build locally due to the way the project is set up)

I would like to pass the -x or --debug flag for debugging purposes, but I cannot modify the existing gitlab pipeline.

Is it possible to hardcode this value in the pom.xml?
I couldn't find anything useful on google.

Comment: My guess is that is is not possible.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The best approach seems to be to talk to the Gitlab admin that you need an additional flag for debugging that can be activated by you if necessary.

Comment: Read the logs first an log exactly where it is failing... apart from that using `mvn clean install` is usually wrong. Only `mvn clean verify` or `mvn clean deploy` if you have an repository manager.